# Run a vim command from a file

Tags: vim

Say I have a file and, in one line of the file, I have written a vim command (for example :setlocal foldmethod=indent)

Is there a way for me to run the command written in that line, without copying it or re-typing it?

Comment: Yes, there is. There are many. For example, if you have the file opened in Vim, and assuming this is an Ex command like in your example, go to the line in question and type `:y|@"` <Enter>. Or if you know the line number *n*, type `:` *n* `y|@"` <Enter>. If you can edit the question and describe what you want to do in more detail it would help improve the chances that you will receive a good answer.

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

If you want, you can create an answer and I shall accept it